# Mongodb: Query documents that matches unknown key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have a collection that contain documents with of the structure:

```
{
  "userId": "57e32f05-fca1-452c-aace-76f35962fe4a",
  "availableSearches": {
    "7fcb6d67-f825-41ca-b47c-fecaedc738c7": {
      "searchType": "RECENT",
      "searchId": "7fcb6d67-f825-41ca-b47c-fecaedc738c7",
      "enabled": false,
    }
    "2b59ee7b-256b-47c2-9573-18676951cb0d": {
      "searchType": "RECENT",
      "searchId": "2b59ee7b-256b-47c2-9573-18676951cb0d",
      "enabled": true,
    }
  }
}
```

I have a list of ids:

```
["7fcb6d67-f825-41ca-b47c-fecaedc738c7", 
 "2b59ee7b-256b-47c2-9573-18676951cb0d",
 ...]
```

The keys of `availableSearches` object are unknown.

I want to get all documents in 1 query, that `availableSearches.${KEY}` exists or `availableSearches.${KEY}.searchId` equals to `${KEY}`. I.e documents that matches the keys in the list.

Is there a way to do it in mongodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   /** Add a new field to all docs where `availableSearches` will converted to an array of [{k:...,v:...},{k:...,v:...}]*/
  {
    $addFields: { availableSearchesConverted: { $objectToArray: "$availableSearches" } }
  },
  /** Match on k field of new array */
  {
    $match: {
      "availableSearchesConverted.k": {
        $all: [ // Use `$in` if you wanted to get docs if atleast one value exists. `$all` checks for all input elements should exists
          "7fcb6d67-f825-41ca-b47c-fecaedc738c7", "2b59ee7b-256b-47c2-9573-18676951cb0d"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  /** Remove newly created field from output */
  {
    $project: {
      availableSearchesConverted: 0
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3H69jPNA6ZO)